# Is it safe to use GridView in Android?

Tags: android, android-gridview

So I know GridView is deprecated, but is it okay to use GridView for production code?

I would like to use it for my game app.

The Android Studio client says it has been deprecated in favor of ConstraintLayout, but trying to set up a grid (which should be a very simple, straightforward task) is such a hassle using ConstraintLayout.

Comment: use recyclerview with gridlayout manager

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> So I know GridView is depreciated

`GridView` is not deprecated, according to [the JavaDocs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView)

> The Android Studio client says it has been depreciated in favor of ConstraintLayout

`GridView` and `ConstraintLayout` are not equivalent things, so that recommendation does not make sense.

`GridLayout` is comparable to `ConstraintLayout`. `GridLayout` is also [not deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout).

> but is it okay to use GridView for production code?

Both `GridView` and `GridLayout` are safe for use in production code. They are obsolete, and I would not recommend that anyone use them, but they are safe.

- If what you want is a scrollable container of items in a grid, you can use `GridView`, though `RecyclerView` and `GridLayoutManager` would be a better choice
- If what you want is a non-scrollable container of items in a grid, you can use `GridLayout` or perhaps `TableLayout`, though `ConstraintLayout` would be a better choice

Comment: You are contradicting yourself. First you say `GridView` and `GridLayout` are not deprecated, then you say they are both obsolete, but safe. Obsolete stuff is deprecated, so could you please clarify?

Comment: @MartinBraun: "Obsolete stuff is deprecated" -- by "obsolete", I mean "the industry has moved on to better solutions". By "deprecated", I mean "the Android team has applied the `@Deprecated` annotation".