# Can I use a GridView instead of RecyclerView for smaller dataset?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-gridview

I have a simple use case to show six images on screen and allow multiselection. The number of images is fixed here. Can I use GridView instead of a RecyclerView for this simple use case?
I read an answer here which says we can. but it is obsolete to use GridView.
[Is it safe to use GridView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57225567/is-it-safe-to-use-gridview-in-android)
My screen is similar to this,

[image]

My screen has only six images on two rows and there is no landscape orientation.

Answer (score 0):

As the name implies, recycler view recycles those individual items. When an item scrolls off the screen and in your case there may be no off-screen items because of the small number, so Yes, you can use grid view and is not deprecated in Android documentation until now

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/widget/GridView